# How do I add external objects to a Max/MSP standalone application

Tags: macos, max-msp-jitter

I'm trying to build a standalone application in Max/MSP and I'm having trouble with a couple of external objects. I've tried explicitly including them through the "Include file..." command in the build window, but they still show up as greyed-out boxes in the exported application. The externals in question have the suffix .mxo.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by manually adding the externals to the application package. I right clicked on the exported application and selected "show package contents".  Then I dropped the externals into `contents > support > extensions`.  That solved the problem.